# A sequence towards to the upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a no empty set with upper bound $m:=\sup{A}\in\mathbb{R}$, then it's simple to prove that exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq A$ such that $$\large x_n\to m$$ for $n\to \infty.$

> The same result holds if $m=+\infty$?

Comment: What did you try, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m=+\infty \implies $$
$$A \text{ is above unbounded}\implies $$

$$(\forall M>0)\;\; (\exists x\in A) \;:\; x>M\implies$$

$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\;:\;(\exists x_n\in A)\;:\; x_n>n$$

the constructed sequence $ (x_n)\in A^{\Bbb N} $ goes to infinity.